# Tomcat version within JBoss?

Tags: tomcat, jboss

What version of Tomcat does JBoss 5.1.0 have embedded?

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Strictly speaking, from JBoss 4.2 and upwards, it doesn't come bundled with Tomcat, but a forked version of it, called JBossWeb. It's separately maintained, independent of the Tomcat code base.

When the fork occured, though, it was at Tomcat 6.0.x.

See [version matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS).